# Is it possible to translate protocol in wso2

Tags: rest, wso2, mqtt

I am new in [WSO2](https://wso2.com/) and I want to know is it possible to translate protocols in wso2. 
For example, translating HTTP/REST into MQTT or CoAP and vice versa.

Regard

Comment: It would be useful to provide some explanation about what you are trying to achieve. I think it is not clear what the requirement is.

Comment: Thank you @Rangas  Yes, I have to explain my question more. We have a system providing some REST APIs, newly We need to presenting those APIs to a system which is working with MQTT protocol. We do not have enough time to developing MQTT's API service. please tell me how we can use WSO2 meeting our need?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Please refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/JMS+Synchronous+Invocations+%3A+Dual+Channel+HTTP-to-JMS) sample. It showcases both scenarios you are requesting.

Tishan